# Find the first and follow set of a given grammar in java

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction

I have been given the problem to complete, and the algorithms to find the first and follow, but my problem is I cant quite find a data structure to implement to find these sets.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class FirstFollowSet {

private final String[] term_tokens = { "begin", "end", ";", "if", "then", "else", "fi", "i", "=", "+", "-", "*",
        "/", "(", ")", "const" };
private final static String[] non_term_tokens = { "Start", "Prog", "Block", "Body", "S", "E", "T", "F" };
private static RuleStack rules;
private Stack<String> firstSet;
private Stack<String> followSet;

private boolean is_terminal(String str) {
    boolean test = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < term_tokens.length; i++) {
        if (str.equals(term_tokens[i]))
            test = true;
    }

    return test;
}

private boolean is_non_term(String str){
    for(int i = 0; i < non_term_tokens.length; i++)
    {
        if(str.equals(non_term_tokens[i]))
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}

private class Rule{
    String def, token;

    public Rule()
    {
        def = "";
        token = "";
    }

    public Rule(String d, String t)
    {
        def = d;
        token = t;
    }

    public String getDef() {
        return def;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "";
        str+= token + " " + def + '\n';
        return str;
    }
}

public class RuleStack{
    Stack<Rule> rules;

    public RuleStack(String grammar)
    {
        if(grammar.equals("G1"));
        {
            rules = new Stack();
            Rule rule = new Rule("Prog", "Start");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("Block #", "Prog");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("begin Body end", "Block");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("begin S end", "Body");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("Body ; S", "Body");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("S", "Body");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("if E then S else S fi", "S");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("if E else S fi", "S");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("i = E", "S");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("Block", "S");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("E + T", "E");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("E * T", "E");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("T", "E");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("T * F", "T");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("T / F", "T");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("F", "T");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("const", "F");
            rules.push(rule);
            rule = new Rule("( E )", "F");
            rules.push(rule);
        }
    }

}

public FirstFollowSet()
{
    rules = new RuleStack("G1");
    firstSet = new Stack();
    followSet = new Stack();
}

public String FindFirstSet(String str, Stack<String> used)
{   
    if(used.contains(str))
    {
        return null;
    }
    String firstToken = "";
    String win = "";
    if(str.indexOf(" ") != -1)
        firstToken = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" "));
    else
        firstToken = str;
    if(is_terminal(firstToken))
    {
        if(!(firstSet.contains(firstToken)))
            win = firstToken;
            if(win.equals("") != true)
                firstSet.push(win);
    }

    else if(is_non_term(firstToken) && !(used.contains(firstToken)))
    {
        used.push(firstToken);
        if(firstToken.equals("lambda"))
        {
            if(!(firstSet.contains(firstToken)))
            win = firstToken;
        }
        else
        {
            RuleStack rules = new RuleStack("G1");
            while(rules.rules.isEmpty() != true)
            {
                Rule winner = rules.rules.pop();
                if(winner.token.equals(firstToken))
                {
                    String test = FindFirstSet(winner.def, used);
                    if(!(test.equals("lambda")))
                    {
                        if(!(firstSet.contains(test)))
                        win = test;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return win;
}

public String findFollowSet(String str)
{
    if(str.equals("S"))
    {
        followSet.push("$");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < non_term_tokens.length; i++)
    {
        if(str.contains(non_term_tokens[i]))
        {
            int index = str.indexOf(non_term_tokens[i]);
            Stack<String> used = new Stack();
            FirstFollowSet test = new FirstFollowSet();
            if(index > 0 && index < str.length()-1)
            {
                test.FindFirstSet(str, used);
                while(test.firstSet.isEmpty() != true)
                {
                    String token = firstSet.pop();
                    if(!(token.equals("lambda")))
                        test.followSet.push(token);
                }
            }

            else if(index > 0 && index == str.length()-1)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirstFollowSet test = new FirstFollowSet();
    Stack<String> used = new Stack();
    test.FindFirstSet("S", used);
    while(test.firstSet.isEmpty() != true)
    {
        String str = test.firstSet.pop();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

}

This is the code I have so far, and the find first set works just fine, but the findfollowset method I'm not quite sure how to implement. The only idea I can seem to come up with is making a stack for each non-terminal symbol, apply the algorithm, and add each terminal symbol returned to the set it belongs to. This method just feel like its more work then necessary.

If anyone has ever solved this problem, or has seen a way to solve this problem I would just like to know what sort of data structure was used and how it the algorithm was implemented for said structure.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and i appreciate any feedback given.

Comment: I'm finding it rather difficult to follow what the code is supposed to do, can you be a bit more specific about it please?

Comment: I wouldn't write my own lexer/parser library.  I'd suggest ANTLR and a Java grammar.

Comment: Use of course, I was given two separate grammars G1 and G2. The code you see so far only implements G1, the constructor for RuleStack does this for me, and the Rule class will hold the lhs of the production as    token and the rhs of the procution as     def now when we call the findFirstSet, the method will pop each rule in the RuleStack by holding a stack of token used, to avoid duplications, called used and a string str that we are to find the first set of. Now This findFirstMethod will reccursivly go through each token related to str, and return the first terminal symbol it produces.

Comment: The follow set is incomplete so you can ignore that method

Comment: @duffymo I cannot use others work, it must be my own design.

Answer (score -3):

package modelo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author celeste
 */
public class Axioma {

```
public char getSimbolo() {
    return simbolo;
}

public void setSimbolo(char simbolo) {
    this.simbolo = simbolo;
}

public ArrayList<Character> getPrimeros() {
    return primeros;
}

public void setPrimeros(ArrayList<Character> primeros) {
    this.primeros = primeros;
}

public ArrayList<Character> getSiguientes() {
    return siguientes;
}

public void setSiguientes(ArrayList<Character> siguientes) {
    this.siguientes = siguientes;
}

public ArrayList<Character> getPredictivos() {
    return predictivos;
}

public void setPredictivos(ArrayList<Character> predictivos) {
    this.predictivos = predictivos;
}

public ArrayList<Character> getRegla() {
    return regla;
}

public void setRegla(ArrayList<Character> regla) {
    this.regla = regla;
}
private ArrayList<Character> primeros = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Character> siguientes = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Character> predictivos = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Character> regla = new ArrayList<>();
private char simbolo;
```

}

Comment: Hello celeste, in what way does this answer the question? Can you add some explanation to your answer?